# Why Is This CSS Not Being Applied When Live?

Tags: html, css

I am running the website [www.gp2aus.com](http://www.gp2aus.com/index.html). When I have updated the foot on the site it shows up perfectly through Dreamweaver when I then click to view in Chrome but when I use Filezilla (FZ) to upload to the server it seems to ignore the pertaining CSS.

[image: Live Website View]

[image: Dreamweaver 'Preview in Chrome' View]

So far I have tried:

1. Updating both the public.html files and another file in FZ
2. Closing down FZ, reconnecting and resetting FZ to update the CSS file completely
3. Waiting for half an hour just incase there was some delay in the larger main.css file transferring over (I realise this was just a 'hit & hope'!
4. Using an online HTML and CSS difference-checker to ensure all of the code created vs uploaded is all the same and these is no difference to any HTML or CSS files

Any ideas what I could consider trying next? I will attach the relevant code below:

HTML

```
<!-- Footer -->
    <span align="right">
        <ul class="footer">
            <li id="copyright-left">SS Web Designs 2017 All rights reserved.</li>
            <li id="copyright-right"><a href="privacy-policy.html">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a> | <a href="termsandconditions.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </span>
```

CSS

```
/* Footer */

ul.footer {
    cursor: default;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-bottom: -3em;
}

ul.footer a {
    color: inherit;
}

    ul.footer li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 1em 0 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

        ul.footer li:last-child {
            padding-right: 0;
        }

            #copyright-left {
                float: left;
            } 

            #copyright-right {
                float: inherit;
            }
```

Even my JSFiddle seems to come out ok.

https://jsfiddle.net/cyum4cw9/

Hmmmmmmmm...

Thanks for the collective wisdom all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS could possibly be cached in your browser or server side. Try clearing the cache on your browser by pressing CTRL + SHFT + DEL.

edit:
if the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/PozxO.png is your desired result, this is how your web page is displayed on my browser.

Comment: Nailed it. In one. So simple. Thanks Devon.